# How can I get a list of solution points from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

I just need a list of numerical solutions for `x[t]`, `x'[t]`, `x''[t]`. While I know how to graph them, I have no idea how to get solutions into a table. Can someone please help?

```
g = 9.81;
v = 20;
θ = Pi/4;
k1 = 0.2;

sol1 = 
  NDSolve[
    {x''[t] == -k1 x'[t]  Sqrt[y'[t]^2 + x'[t]^2], 
     y''[t] == -k1  y'[t]  Sqrt[y'[t]^2 + x'[t]^2] - g m, 
     x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == v Cos[θ], y'[0] == v Sin[θ]}, 
    {x, y}, {t,0, 10}];

tkoncni = t /. FindRoot[y[t] /. sol1, {t, 1}];

gr11 = 
  Plot[y[t] /. sol1, {t, 0, tkoncni}, 
    PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y(t)"}];

gr12 = 
  ParametricPlot[{x[t] /. sol1[[1]], y[t] /. sol1}, {t, 0, tkoncni}, 
    PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "y(t)"}];
```

Comment: can't you use Table or so?

Comment: i know i have to use table, i just dont know how to use it correctly

Answer (score 2):

The easy way to do it IMO is to extract the interpolating functions from your solution.

```
g = 9.81;
v = 20;
θ = Pi/4;
k1 = 0.2;
m = 1.;

sol1 =
  NDSolve[
   {x''[t] == -k1 x'[t] Sqrt[y'[t]^2 + x'[t]^2], 
    y''[t] == -k1 y'[t] Sqrt[y'[t]^2 + x'[t]^2] - g m, 
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == v Cos[θ], y'[0] == v Sin[θ]}, 
   {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}]

{xF, yF} = sol1[[1, All, 2]];
tmax = t /. FindRoot[yF[t], {t, 1}]
```

> `1.58915`

```
Table[{xF[t], xF'[t], xF''[t]}, {t, Subdivide[tmax, 10]}]
```

> ```
> {{0., 14.1421, -56.5685}, {1.74666, 8.75671, -20.1819}, 
>  {2.93728, 6.49064, -10.0301}, {3.8629, 5.26585, -5.92728}, 
>  {4.63437, 4.49283, -4.04329}, {5.30152, 3.92479, -3.23141}, 
>  {5.88598, 3.43832, -2.9428}, {6.39581, 2.9813, -2.81483}, 
>  {6.83461, 2.54532, -2.66073}, {7.20639, 2.13967, -2.43278}, 
>  {7.51685, 1.77504, -2.14991}}
> ```

```
Table[{yF[t], yF'[t], yF''[t]}, {t, Subdivide[tmax, 10]}]
```

> ```
> {{0., 14.1421, -66.3785}, {1.64027, 7.49102, -27.0749}, 
>  {2.54638,   4.19187, -16.2878}, {3.02848, 1.98633, -12.0458}, 
>  {3.2019, 0.248938, -10.034}, {3.12038, -1.24218, -8.78726}, 
>  {2.8168, -2.54778, -7.62941}, {2.32084, -3.66031, -6.35408}, 
>  {1.6645, -4.56506, -5.03796}, {0.880709, -5.26691, -3.82158}, 
>  {-4.16334*10^-16, -5.78996, -2.79726}}
> ```